# Unable to change directory with remote shell

Tags: linux

I have been trying my hand at creating a remote shell in C for Unix.  I am able to connect to the server and pull commands off of it. However I am unable to change my pwd, even though seems to operating correctly.  I give it a directory and if that directory does not exist I will receive an error. Below is the quick shell I have been testing.

```
  while(1)
{

  for( n = 0; n < BUFFER_SIZE; n++)
{
  command[n] = '\0';
}

  write( sockfd, buffer, strlen( buffer ) );

  read( sockfd, command, BUFFER_SIZE );

  fprintf( stderr, "Command: %s\n", command );

  dup2(sockfd, 2);
  dup2(sockfd, 1);
  dup2(sockfd, 0);

   execlp( "/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *)NULL );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec`'ing a `cd` command doesn't change the working directory of the program that calls `exec`. It forks a process that changes *its own* working directory, then exits.

You'll have to treat the `cd` command specially by invoking the `chdir` system call for it rather than `exec`.

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is not a program, it is a shell builtin command, which changes the cwd for the shell, not for the program that spawned that shell. You are spawning a new shell for every command, so the changed cwd does not persist.

You could either try to catch invocations of `cd` and run `chdir()` yourself, or spawn a single interactive shell and use pipes or a pty (pseudo terminal) to communicate with it.